# Cluster Creation HdInsight and Cores Asignation. Tunning apache spark submit

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

I want to process a 250gb gzip(filename.json.gzip) file in Azure Hd Insight cluster with Spark. But I could not do it.

I guess because of a bad relationship between cores, ram, vCPU(s)so I would like to kwnow the better cluster to create and Spark configuration to send.

Currently I'm using this instance:

- 6 nodes of a cluster E8a v4 (8 Cores, 64 GB RAM)

And My Spark Configuration Are:

- Driver Memory: 10Gb
- Driver Cores: 7
- Executor Memory: 10Gb
- Executor Cores: 7
- Num Executors: 7

So, there is a better choise in the Azure HDInsight Clusters ([Link To the all avaiable clusters i can create](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/hdinsight/)) and in the Spark submition configuration?

Answer (score -1):

> The performance of your Apache Spark jobs depends on multiple factors. These performance factors include: how your data is stored, how the cluster is configured, and the operations that are used when processing the data.

Common challenges you might face include: memory constraints due to improperly sized executors, long-running operations, and tasks that result in cartesian operations.

There are also many optimizations that can help you overcome these challenges, such as caching, and allowing for data skew.

For more details, refer to [Optimize Apache Spark jobs in HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-perf).